# Counting lines of text

Tags: grammar, counters

> 最初の一行を読んだ。
> She read the first line.

Is 一行 pronounced as いっこう or いちぎょう?

Is a line of text just 行 or is it 一行? I can't figure out if 一行 is simply 'line' or 'one line'. I'm guessing that 行 is a counter and needs 一 in front of it. It would be ungrammatical to write 最初の行, right?

Just to confirm my understanding, presumably "she read the first **two** lines" would be 最初の二行{にぎょう?}を読んだ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 最初の行.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the example, it is the counter for line: [いちぎょう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E8%A1%8C_%28%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1%E3%81%8E%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%29/#jn-12376), にぎょう, さんぎょう, よんぎょう, ごぎょう, ろくぎょう, ななぎょう, はちぎょう, きゅうぎょう, じゅうぎょう.

[一行{いっこう}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%80%E8%A1%8C_%28%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%29/#jn-13191) means a party/group of people who travel together.